# How can I adjust correlation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, autocorrelation

Say I measure the correlation 50x between two variables, and it is consistently 0.8. Later on I realize there's a consistent systematic constant offset in one of my variables let's call it x. How can I adjust the correlation now? Isn't it just by simply subtracting the offset from each x variable?

Is there a formula somewhere?

Comment: Which correlation are you looking at? Pearson's, Spearman's, Kendall's, or some other?

Comment: Spearman correlation and pearson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Pearson's correlation is a measure of linear dependence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) Adding a constant to one of your vectors amounts to shifting the entire scatterplot either vertically or horizontally (depending on what variable you add your constant to). The line of best fit will not change. Therefore, Pearson's correlation coefficient will not change at all.

  ```
   > set.seed(1)# for replicability
   > x <- rnorm(20); y <- rnorm(20)
   > cor(x,y,method="pearson")
   [1] -0.2175249
   > cor(x+2,y,method="pearson")# same result
   [1] -0.2175249
  ```
- Similarly, [Spearman's correlation coefficient is just Pearson's correlation calculated on ranks.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) But ranks among a vector do not change if we add a constant to the entire vector. Therefore, Spearman's correlation will also be unchanged.

  ```
   > cor(x,y,method="spearman")
   [1] -0.2165414
   > cor(x+2,y,method="spearman")# same result
   [1] -0.2165414
  ```
- Finally, the exact same holds for [Kendall's correlation coefficient, which is also a rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient).

  ```
   > cor(x,y,method="kendall")
   [1] -0.1473684
   > cor(x+2,y,method="kendall")# same result
   [1] -0.1473684
  ```